# Debian 4 binary i386 upgrade to latest Debian on a server

Tags: linux, debian, installation

I started working at a new company and discovered two servers that have not been switched on in 7 years. They are Dell PowerEdge R200 servers with core 2 duo processors.

I want to utilize these servers but need to get into them first. They only have Debian skeleton and no GUI. I have no prior knowledge of how to work these servers with this OS. I need to get GUI on this to see what programs have been installed and what this server was used for. I was able to change the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `deb http://archive.debian.org/debian etch main contrib non-free` and tried running `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get update` but neither of those could connect to the server with `Temporary failure resolving archive.debian.org to download packages` to be able to get GUI/Desktop environment on the server. Please excuse my ignorance  as I am learning on the go.

Please would anyone be able to advise how I can get GUI/Desktop environment on this machine without doing a fresh install and losing everything on this server. Please note that I set the network configuration up and I can get internet and see the archive server but it keeps on saying that the files are not bzip2. I tried changing to `http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free` for a test but that gets stuck on 99% waiting for headers after Ign htpp://deb.debian.org buster release and then has multiple errors.

I have a bootable live current release usb available. I tried using it but it looks like it is going to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 2):

Don't.

First, as a general rule, don't make big changes on a system that you don't know how to use yet. (That is, if you're not familiar with Debian aside from copypasting commands, it's not time to do release upgrades yet.)

Second, don't make big changes on a system if you don't know what it's running. Is it a web server, a mail server, an IRC server? If you don't know what's in there, then you won't be able to know whether anything broke after the changes.

(Third, don't install GUI packages on servers. It might not harm having some light desktop environment in there, but you should instead manage it remotely via SSH most of the time, and the desktop will just waste resources.)

(Fourth, you should've made a backup first.)

Finally, I'm not sure whether you *can* upgrade Debian straight from 4 to 11 in the first place. You might need to do a fresh install anyway.

Debian went through big architectural changes across this range of 7 releases. If you upgrade version by version it might still work; if you try upgrading straight to buster or bullseye, I strongly suspect you'll just end up with an unbootable system that you'll have to reinstall anyway. In fact I'm not even sure if apt/dpkg from Debian 4 will even recognize the package formats from now.

Many libraries have changed their APIs, and some completely removed. If the server is running some program that itself is no longer in the repositories (or indeed one that never was), it won't get updated for the new libraries. This still works out better on Debian than some other distros, because many libraries can have different versions installed side by side and the old packages may just stick around after upgrades, but they also might not.

And you probably might *want* a fresh install for various other reasons – changing the filesystem to a more modern one, installing 64-bit instead of 32-bit, and so on.

---

So if you want the server to *work like used to* then keep it as-is for now, and spend some time figuring out what's in there. Then do a clean install of latest Debian and try to move all that stuff to the new server, and once it's working clean out the old one.

On the other hand, if you want to use the server for *completely new tasks*, then give it a completely new installation as well. Just make a full backup of the old system first, e.g. create a tarball or raw image of the entire disk.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and feedback. Please would you maybe share recourses to how to setup a SSH that will be easy enough to understand. I mainly know Mac and Windows. I have little knowledge on Linux and last time I had done anything with Linux itself was about 8 years ago installing Linux Mint or something of that storts. I am willing to learn, I am just looking for appropriate info to get me to where I need to be.  Thank you and kind regards, Krynauw Kruger